# Ravendb document design

Tags: ravendb

In our raven based application we are starting to experience major performance issues when the master document starts increasing in size, as it holds a lot of collections that keep growing.  As such I am now planning a major data redesign that is likely to take months and I want to be sure I'm on the right track before I do so.

The current design looks like this:

```
Community
    {
      id:,
      name,
      //other properties
      members[
               {
                 id:,
                 name:,
                 date of birth:
                 //etc
               },
               {
                 //another member, this list could potentially grow to hundreds of thousands
               }
           ],

      league
         [
           {
             id,
             name,
             seasons[
                       {...},
                       {
                          id:,
                          divisions
                             [
                               {
                                 id:,
                                 name:
                                 matches[
                                   {
                                      id:,
                                      //match details
                                    },
                                    {
                                      //another match. there could be hundreds here in a big league
                                     },
                                     {}
```

As we started hitting performance issues, we started using transformers to only load what is needed, but that didn't solve the problem fully  as some of our leagues are a couple mb's just on their own.  The other issue is we always need to be doing member checks to check for admin/membership rights so the members list is always needed.

I understand I could omit the member list completely using a transformer and use an index for membership checks, but the problem remains about what to do, when a member is added , that list will need to be loaded and with an upcoming project there is a potential for it to grow to half a million people or more.

So my plan is separate each entity into it's own document, so in the case of leagues, I will have a league document, and a match document, with matches containing {leagueId, season number, division number, other match details}.

Each member will have their own document with a list of community document Id's they're a member of.

I'm just a bit worried, that using this design, is missing the whole point of a document db and we may as well have used sql, or do you think I'm on the right track with approach?

Comment: which types of issues or on which operations? large docs should mean longer time for indexing

Comment: I don't think the architect was particularly clued up because there is almost no indexes. Reading and writing  is done with a load of the community document.  This means it's slow with almost every operation on a large community.  So I could keep current structure and use indexes for all queries, but writing will still require a load of the community document .

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having separate documents and relationships between them. Sometimes this makes sense for your app and for your model. Raven allows for this in cleaner/nicer way than a lot of other NoSQL solutions.